# custom dropdownList in Django

Tags: django, database, insert

How to make a custom drop-down list in Django?

```
# model
class FinancialYearSetting(models.Model):
    financial_year_setting = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.financial_year_setting

class GoalMaster(models.Model):
    Fy_choices = (
        ('2011-2018', '2011-2018'),
        ('2018-2019', '2018-2019'),
    )

    finacialYr = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Fy_choices)
    employee_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

So I want to make custom drop-down list using database without using the syntax below:

```
 finacialYr = models.ForeignKey(FinancialYearSetting, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I do not want id(pk) values.
There should be text field and value, both should be text.
Please suggest how I could bind it to html.

Comment: you can make the financial_year_setting field as `primary_key=True` and still use ForeignKey. Is that enough?

Comment: I do not need to make ForeignKey? to make tuple Fy_choices = (
        ('2017-2018', '2011-2018'),
        ('2018-2019', '2018-2019'),
    )using database

Comment: If financial_year_setting is the primary_key, both text field and value will be '2017-2018'. See, if that does what you want.

Comment: I want to make a dropdownlist using database whose textfields and valuefields should be same